# MyBatis - Map a stored proc output param value to a POJO

Tags: java, stored-procedures, ibatis, mybatis, pojo

Basically I want to map an output parameter from a Stored Proc, which is Numeric, to a property of a basic POJO. This is proving a little more tricky that I imagined. I have the following setup:

```
<resultMap id="BaseResultMap" type="myPOJO">
<result property="pojoPropertyToHaveValueMappedTo" />
</resultMap>

<select id="selectOne" parameterType="com.ParameterType" statementType="CALLABLE" resultMap="BaseResultMap">
{call theDB.my_stored_proc
(#{numberSpReturns,jdbcType=NUMERIC, mode=OUT})}
/select>
```

The call out to the Stored Proc is fine, and I get the numeric value returning I expect.  However surely I must be able to map this returned value to a property in my POJO???

Comment: If you set your result property to pull from a column that doesn't exits, I believe it will throw an error. If you set a breakpoint just before that error location, I believe you can debug the output and see what result columns/properties are available. The column with data may be something as simple as "value", or perhaps whatever the name of the variable is.

Answer (score 0):

Result maps are meant for traversing through result sets. In your case, you can define your own TypeHandler to handle NUMERIC to POJO mapping. Something like this:

`(#{numberSpReturns,jdbcType=NUMERIC, mode=OUT, javaType=myPOJO, typeHandler=yourTypeHandler})`